# kernel: audit(1298407016.926:258): avc: denied

Tags: ftp, rhel5, selinux

My Server is showing following text in its log file.

kernel: audit(1298407016.926:258): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=13945 comm="httpd" dest=21 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ftp_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket

I did not seem to understand the text. is is related to SElinux  . my server is rhel5.

Thank you in advance.
Prabin

Answer (score 1):

Apache(httpd) try connect to ftp server(probably upgrade scripts).

If you need scripts to be able to connect you can set the httpd_can_network_connect boolean on:

```
 setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```